# setting up localDB for Entityframework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I have an c# .net 4.0 application which connects to sqlexpress.I want to make the change so that it connects to localDB. I will reuse the same mdf .

Presently the config file has the following entry

```
 <configuration>
 <configSections>
 <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

 </configSections>
 <startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
 </startup>

   <entityFramework>
     <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
     <parameters>
      <parameter value="Data Source=.\EMSERVER; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
     </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
   <providers>
       <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"   type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
 </entityFramework>
```

Also the in the code

string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";

```
        // Initialize the connection string builder for the
        // underlying provider.
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder =
        new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        // Set the properties for the data source.
        sqlBuilder.DataSource = serverName;
        sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
        sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        sqlBuilder.Enlist = true;
        sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;

        // Build the SqlConnection connection string.
        string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

        // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder =
        new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

        //Set the provider name.
        entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;

        // Set the provider-specific connection string.
        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

        // Set the Metadata location.
        entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/TrendDataModel.csdl|
        res://*/TrendDataModel.ssdl|
        res://*/TrendDataModel.msl";

        return entityBuilder.ToString();
```

Should we have both code and app.config ? How do i change it to connect to test.mdf file which is in c:\temp. or is it enough i change the connection string directly in the code?

Comment: i have copied the app.config in the question and connectionstring is also formed inside the code

Answer (score 0):

EF provides two types of DbContext/ObjectContext constructor methods.

One of them takes the name of connection string (from configuration file) another one takes the EntityConnection instance that is wrapper of ConnectionString. So that you can work with one or the other.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456849